# Printing json response values

Tags: java, json

I have called an api using unirest and i am successfully getting response of json but i am not able to print values of json response . I am new to json so i will be glad if someone can help me . The response i am getting is

> [{"number":"3323-2323232","updated_at":"2018-04-09
>   11:15:53","created_at":"2018-04-09 11:15:53","id":2,"message":"Dear
>   dasdas! your payment against Booking is due. Kindly make the due
>   payment.","status":0}]

How can i print values of it ?

Code of mine for getting response of json is

```
          //calling thread to take json
  // calling to json data url          
  HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("............").
        header("accept",  "application/json"). asJson();

   System.out.println(response.getBody());

  try {
   JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("results");

                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    System.out.println("Number : "+jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("number"));

                }

  }
  catch (Throwable e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the responsible code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for your response . I have added the code for calling url to get response

Comment: How   JSONArray jsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("results"); can work ? string "results" is not json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String number = jsonobject.getString("number");
        String updated_at = jsonobject.getString("updated_at");
        String created_at = jsonobject.getString("created_at");
        String id = jsonobject.getString("id");
        String message = jsonobject.getString("message");
        String status = jsonobject.getString("status");
                }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but i am still getting an error "org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:208)"

Comment: can you post your first line i.e. json array declaration line

Comment: JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

Comment: Try:    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response.getBody().toString());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168559/discussion-between-prabhav-and-fahad-pirzada).